# Installing Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a pre-built RAID Array

Tags: server, system-installation, raid

So I've got a RAID array built (Via the ASUS motherboard, 2 disks, RAID 1).

When I try to install Ubuntu server on it, the process runs as normal (Apart from the drive is detected as `md126p1` rather than the normal `sda` or `sdb` etc).

But then on reboot, I just get the little blinking cursor, and nothing happens ...

Have I missed something here? Is there something else I'm supposed to do?

Comment: How did you install it? I had a similar problem, unrelated to drive. The installer installed grub onto the USB I was installing from so when I rebooted it just sat there.

Comment: Yep ... That was a problem I was having before as well Lol ... I've tried to get around it this time by pulling out the USB before it detects the hardware, which doesn't try to install grub onto SDA ... It says it has installed grub onto  /dev/md126p1

Comment: What is the boot order in the BIOS? Does it recognise the RAID array as a boot device?

Comment: Yeah, it has Volume0 (The raid array) as the first boot device, and also choosing it from the boot menu takes me to the same flashy cursor ... I have found a different issue that may be causing it, which is that the RAID array 'status' says 'Initialize' (Intel Rapid Storage Technology) ... Now I'm not sure if this is saying it is Initializing, or if there is something I'm supposed to do to initialize it ... There is no option to do that ... It may just be a case of 'wait out' :/

Comment: Okay ... After reading some Intel posts, I've found that the 'Initialize' status is normal until an OS is installed (Although it only mentions Windows) ... So, I think I'm going to go back to my initial thought, that it may possibly be that I've installed GRUB in the wrong place ...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured it out ...

The default location for the grub install in my case was `/dev/md126p1` ... But I needed to change it to `/dev/md126` ...

This is a common occurrence for me with the GRUB installation with Ubuntu Server editions, that the default location to install  GRUB, is always wrong. I have always had to 'execute a shell' to find out the name ubuntu has given the drive I wish to install it to ...

With Ubuntu Desktop installation, you are shown what drives are available to install GRUB onto, and makes it much easier to decide where to install it to. Does anyone think they should incorporate this into the server edition? Or does everyone think I'm just an idiot Lol?

Comment: When you choose no to the grub install dialog you'll be asked to choose the destination of the grub installation.