# How to change grub install location

Tags: boot, server, grub2, raid

The problem is exactly as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517531/installing-ubuntu-server-14-04-on-a-pre-built-raid-array). According to the answer from that thread grub location should be changed from `/dev/md126p1` to `/dev/md126`. What I don't quite understand is how to do it during installation proccess.
System is Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS.

```
# lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype
    NAME                MOUNTPOINT LABEL      SIZE FSTYPE
sda                                     931.5G
├─sda1                         oblsud:0   487M linux_raid_member
│ └─md0             /boot                 972M ext4
├─sda2                                      1K
├─sda5                         oblsud:1  11.2G linux_raid_member
│ └─md1             [SWAP]               22.3G swap
├─sda6                         oblsud:2  93.1G linux_raid_member
│ └─md2                                 186.1G LVM2_member
│   └─system-rootfs /                   186.1G ext4
└─sda7                         oblsud:3 826.7G linux_raid_member
  └─md3                                   1.6T LVM2_member
    └─storage-home  /home                 1.6T ext4
sdb                                     931.5G
├─sdb1                         oblsud:0   487M linux_raid_member
│ └─md0             /boot                 972M ext4
├─sdb2                                      1K
├─sdb5                         oblsud:1  11.2G linux_raid_member
│ └─md1             [SWAP]               22.3G swap
├─sdb6                         oblsud:2  93.1G linux_raid_member
│ └─md2                                 186.1G LVM2_member
│   └─system-rootfs /                   186.1G ext4
└─sdb7                         oblsud:3 826.7G linux_raid_member
  └─md3                                   1.6T LVM2_member
    └─storage-home  /home                 1.6T ext4
sdc                                     931.5G
├─sdc1                         oblsud:0   487M linux_raid_member
│ └─md0             /boot                 972M ext4
├─sdc2                                      1K
├─sdc5                         oblsud:1  11.2G linux_raid_member
│ └─md1             [SWAP]               22.3G swap
├─sdc6                         oblsud:2  93.1G linux_raid_member
│ └─md2                                 186.1G LVM2_member
│   └─system-rootfs /                   186.1G ext4
└─sdc7                         oblsud:3 826.7G linux_raid_member
  └─md3                                   1.6T LVM2_member
    └─storage-home  /home                 1.6T ext4
sdd                                     931.5G
├─sdd1                         oblsud:0   487M linux_raid_member
│ └─md0             /boot                 972M ext4
├─sdd2                                      1K
├─sdd5                         oblsud:1  11.2G linux_raid_member
│ └─md1             [SWAP]               22.3G swap
├─sdd6                         oblsud:2  93.1G linux_raid_member
│ └─md2                                 186.1G LVM2_member
│   └─system-rootfs /                   186.1G ext4
└─sdd7                         oblsud:3 826.7G linux_raid_member
  └─md3                                   1.6T LVM2_member
    └─storage-home  /home                 1.6T ext4
sr0                                      1024M


# parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-60M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   primary                   boot, raid
 2      513MB   1000GB  1000GB  extended
 5      513MB   12.5GB  12.0GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)  raid
 6      12.5GB  113GB   100GB   logical                   raid
 7      113GB   1000GB  888GB   logical                   raid


Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-60M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   primary                   boot, raid
 2      513MB   1000GB  1000GB  extended
 5      513MB   12.5GB  12.0GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)  raid
 6      12.5GB  113GB   100GB   logical                   raid
 7      113GB   1000GB  888GB   logical                   raid


Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-60M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   primary                   boot, raid
 2      513MB   1000GB  1000GB  extended
 5      513MB   12.5GB  12.0GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)  raid
 6      12.5GB  113GB   100GB   logical                   raid
 7      113GB   1000GB  888GB   logical                   raid


Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-60M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   primary                   boot, raid
 2      513MB   1000GB  1000GB  extended
 5      513MB   12.5GB  12.0GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)  raid
 6      12.5GB  113GB   100GB   logical                   raid
 7      113GB   1000GB  888GB   logical                   raid


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/storage-home: 1775GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1775GB  1775GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/system-rootfs: 200GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  200GB  200GB  ext4


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md0: 1019MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1019MB  1019MB  ext4


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md1: 24.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  24.0GB  24.0GB  linux-swap(v1)


Error: /dev/md2: unrecognised disk label
Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md2: 200GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

Error: /dev/md3: unrecognised disk label
Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md3: 1775GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Comment: Will you edit your question and add the output of: `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l`?

Comment: Unfortunately system has been already installed with software RAID support. So I suppose the output of these commands would be irrelevant.

Comment: They will have relevance.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Sorry if I should know this, but you are saying you can't boot into the server?  You are just getting a flashing cursor?

Comment: Ah. I think it's my fault, I shold've made it clear from the start. For the moment OS is running just fine by means of software RAID (`md`). But I do get blank screen with a flashing cursor whenever I install OS on a pre-built RAID array (which is based on Intel Matrix system). Ubuntu detects that array as /dev/md126p1 and installs the system along with GRUB to it. After installation is complete, I can't boot into the server whatever I do. But I must recall that my question was how to change GRUB install location.